# Big Integers in Memoized Recursive Fibonacci (Y)

Tags: javascript

I've written a version of Y that automatically caches old values in a closure using memoization.

```
var Y = function (f, cache) {
    cache = cache || {};
    return function (x) {
        if (x in cache) return cache[x];
        var result = f(function (n) {
            return Y(f, cache)(n);
        })(x);
        return cache[x] = result;
    };
};
```

Now, when `almostFibonacci` (defined below) is passed into the above function, it returns the value of a large Fibonacci number comfortably.

```
var almostFibonacci = function (f) {
    return function (n) {
        return n === '0' || n === '1' ? n : f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    };
};
```

However, after a certain value (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`), integers in JavaScript (owing to their **IEEE-754 double precision format**) are not accurate. So, considering the fact that the only mathematical operations in the Fibonacci function above are addition and subtraction and since operators **cannot be overloaded** in JavaScript, I wrote naïve implementations of the sum and difference functions (that both use strings to support big integers) which are as follows.

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

var difference = function (first, second) {
    first = first.reverse();
    second = second.reverse();
    var firstDigit,
    secondDigit,
    differenceDigits = [],
        differenceDigit,
        carry = 0,
        index = 0;
    while (index < first.length || index < second.length || carry !== 0) {
        firstDigit = index < first.length ? parseInt(first[index], 10) : 0;
        secondDigit = index < second.length ? parseInt(second[index], 10) : 0;
        differenceDigit = firstDigit - secondDigit - carry;
        differenceDigits.push((differenceDigit + (differenceDigit < 0 ? 10 : 0)).toString());
        carry = differenceDigit < 0 ? 1 : 0;
        index++;
    }
    differenceDigits.reverse();
    while (differenceDigits[0] === '0') differenceDigits.shift();
    return differenceDigits.join('');
};

var sum = function (first, second) {
    first = first.reverse();
    second = second.reverse();
    var firstDigit,
    secondDigit,
    sumDigits = [],
        sumDigit,
        carry = 0,
        index = 0;
    while (index < first.length || index < second.length || carry !== 0) {
        firstDigit = index < first.length ? parseInt(first[index], 10) : 0;
        secondDigit = index < second.length ? parseInt(second[index], 10) : 0;
        sumDigit = firstDigit + secondDigit + carry;
        sumDigits.push((sumDigit % 10).toString());
        carry = sumDigit > 9 ? 1 : 0;
        index++;
    }
    sumDigits.reverse();
    while (sumDigits[0] === '0') sumDigits.shift();
    return sumDigits.join('');
};
```

Now, by themselves, both these functions work perfectly.<sup>1</sup>

I have now updated the `almostFibonacci` function to as follows to use the **sum** function instead of **+** and the **difference** function instead of the **-** operator.

```
var almostFibonacci = function (f) {
    return function (n) {
        return n === '0' || n === '1' ? n : sum(f(difference(n, '1')), f(difference(n, '2')));
    };
};
```

As you may have guessed, this does work. It crashes the fiddle in case of even a small number like 10.

**Question:** What could be wrong? All the functions here work perfectly individually. But in tandem, they seem to fail. Can anyone here help me debug this particularly complex scenario?

*<sup>1</sup>Except an edge case for the difference function. It requires the first argument to be larger than the second.*

Comment: Did you mean for this to be conditional instead of an assignment (error I receive from jsfiddle when I pasted it all)? `return cache[x] = result;`

Comment: That is not the problem. It is perfectly valid. Just not a good practice that JSHint complains about.

Comment: I assumed this, I was simply asking to make sure this was his intention. @Siddharth could you paste a link to a fiddle?

Comment: Ah. Alright. That was intentional, yes. I haven't posted it into a fiddle because it crashes Chrome straight up. Nonetheless, I'm on my phone now. I'll post it on one and link to it as soon as I'm at my desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, by themselves, both these functions work perfectly - Except an edge case for the difference function. It requires the first argument to be larger than the second.

And that's the problem. In your fibonacci algorithm you're at some point calculating `difference("2", "2")`, which needs to yield `"0"` to work. It does however return the empty string `""`, which is not tested against as your guard condition for the recursion. When in the next step computing `difference("", "1")`, the function will fall into an infinite loop.

Solutions:

- Fix that edge case (you still won't need to cope with negative numbers)
- Don't use strings for the ordinal number, but only for the fibonacci number itself. You hardly will try the compute the (2<sup>53</sup>+1)th fibonacci number, will you? I would assume this to be a significant speed improvement as well.

  ```
  var fibonacci = Y(function(fib) {
      return function(n) {
          if (n == 0) return "0";
          if (n == 1) return "1";
          return sum(fib(n-1), fib(n-2));
      };
  });
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much once again!

Comment: By the way, don't you mean 2^53 - 1? Since that is equal to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved the problem at hand.

**Changes**:

- I removed the `while (differenceDigits[0] === '0') differenceDigits.shift();` statement. Even though this outputs differences without truncated leading zeros, it outputs a `'0'` in case of an edge case like `difference('2', '2')`.
- I edited the return statement in the `almostFibonacci` function to `return n == 0 || n == 1 ? n : sum(f(difference(n, '1')), f(difference(n, '2')));`. Notice that I'm checking for 0 and not '0' with a non strict equality operator.<sup>1</sup>

*<sup>1</sup>The reason I'm doing `n == 0` as opposed to `n === '0'` is because in JavaScript, `'00000' == 0` but `'00000' !== '0'` and **in my new updated difference function, without truncated leading zeros, I can't guarantee the number of zeros for a zero output.** Well, actually I can. There would be as many zeros as the length of n.*

[100th Fibonacci - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6b7vrmo/2/)